# How do I create a class with multiple instantiation options

Tags: rust

I want to build a class in Rust that allows for variety and convenience in its instantiation similar to the way that `std::net::TcpStream` can be provided multiple inputs to its `connect` method.

I have the following tests, but very little idea of the structs or traits I need to build to achieve this result.

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::Ipv4Network;
    use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

    #[test]
    fn instantiation() {
        let net_addr = Ipv4Addr::new(10, 0, 0, 0);
        let net_mask = Ipv4Addr::new(255, 255, 255, 240);

        // Instantiate an Ipv4Network using two Ipv4Addrs.
        let with_addrs = Ipv4Network::new(net_addr, net_mask);

        // Instantiate an Ipv4Network using an Ipv4Addr and a prefix integer.
        let with_addr_prefix = Ipv4Network::new(net_addr, 28);

        // Instantiate an Ipv4Network using two strings.
        let with_strings = Ipv4Network::new("10.0.0.0", "255.255.255.240");

        // Instantiate an Ipv4Network using a string and a prefix integer.
        let with_prefix = Ipv4Network::new("10.0.0.0", 28);

        // Instantiate an Ipv4Network using a string with CIDR notation.
        let with_cidr = Ipv4Network::new("10.0.0.0/28");
    }
}
```

My understanding is that `std::net::TcpStream` accomplishes its multiple `connect` inputs through the [ToSocketAddrs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/net/trait.ToSocketAddrs.html) trait, the source of which can be found [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/net/addr.rs#L308). How exactly `std::net:TcpStream::connect` [uses ToSocketAddrs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/net/tcp.rs#L91) isn't clear to me, but I imagine I should be able to define an `Ipv4Network` as follows:

```
pub struct Ipv4Network {
    addr: Ipv4Addr,
    mask: Ipv4Addr,
}
```

If that's true then how do I go about creating a trait (say `ToIpv4Network`) that functions like `ToSocketAddrs` does for `std::net:TcpStream`?

What should the meat of

```
impl ToIpv4Network for (Ipv4Addr, Ipv4Addr) {
...
}
```

look like? Is that even the right path to start going down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a reasonable place to start working from.  I think one of your issues is that the interfaces you have defined are going to be difficult to accomplish as written by using a trait.

So, let's talk about the way that `ToSocketAddrs` works.  First, let's just quickly note and then ignore the fact that the `ToSocketAddrs` trait returns an `Iterator` of `SocketAddrs`.  We're ignoring it because it's actually irrelevant to the question at hand.

Here's the body of the trait declaration:

```
pub trait ToSocketAddrs {
    type Iter: Iterator<Item=SocketAddr>;
    fn to_socket_addrs(&self) -> Result<Self::Iter>;
}
```

The purpose of this trait is to allow it to be used as a [trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/traits.html) in a generic function/struct.  Broadly speaking, trait bounds are a way of writing a generic but getting the Rust compiler to ensure that the type that ends up instantiating the generic implements the behavior defined by that trait (or traits.

In the case of `ToSocketAddrs` this means that a type can (potentially) be converted to a `SocketAddr`. The code that is called inside of `connect` then makes use of the `to_socket_addrs` function defined on the trait.

As a brief aside, I said potentially because `to_socket_addrs` returns a `Result` which can take on values of `Ok(<success-type>)` and `Err(<failure-type>)`, which is probably a good pattern to model your trait on.

This is the key point that relates to why I think your desired interface is maybe not ideal (or implementable, Rust doesn't directly support arity, or any other type of function overloading).  Passing a trait bound generic parameter is the easiest way to accomplish your goal.